# How to handle Primefaces tabView's 'OnTabShow' using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jquery-events

I guess the title is pretty self explanatory! I'm using Primefaces tabView, and added an event handler inline like so:

```
<p:tabView effect="fade" id="myTabView" style="background:none;" dynamic="true" styleClass="myTabs" onTabShow="myShowFunction()">
.
.
</p:tabView>
```

I want to use jQuery's `on` to bind an event handler using the tabs show event. I tried using `on('ontabsshow', myShowFunction)`, but it doesn't work. I need to update a global variable when the tabs change (after completion of the transition). Hence I need my code to be placed in the same script which has the global's declaration.

Any guidance?

Comment: Maybe just a typo? The attribute is called `onTabShow`. The event you named in the jquery `on` function has two "s": `ontabsshow` ?

Comment: Guess what, even I was confused with the term, but I tried with the other spelling, it doesn't work!

Comment: Looking at the Primeface sources quickly you can see that they use the String themselves: `handleAttribute("onTabShow", _onTabShow);`
Maybe this is case sensitive and you need to name it exactly this way?

Comment: Aha... lemme try this one...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm a bit late... however

There is no real `onTabShow` event on the browser side as you would expect. Primefaces generates specific js code in order to call your myShowFunction function at the right time.

JQuery does not help here.

Just put your function inside a script section (after your tabView component) :

```
<script>
    function myShowFunction() {
        //Update your variable here
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps